# Orthonormal Hamel Basis is equivalent to finite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Consider a Hilbert space which is infinite dimensional. If it is separable, it is well known that an orthonormal basis will be countable, while a hamel basis will be uncountable (since it is a complete space), therefore the two bases cannot coincide. But how can we prove that those two bases cannot be equal if our space is not separable?

Comment: Nothing changes: if $\{ e_{\alpha}\}$ is an ONB, then the expansion coefficients of an $x\in H$ are the scalar products, so an infinite linear combination is not at the same time a finite linear combination.

Comment: Basically we get that any x is perpendicular to all but finitely many e_i's. However, Tomasz's answer made it clear. It was a very simple question but I didn't try to think of such a simple approach. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument can be made rather simpler: if you have a given ON basis $e_i$, $i\in I$, the vector $v=\sum_{n\in {\bf N}} 2^{-n}e_{i_n}$, where $i_n$ are distinct, is clearly not a finite linear combination of the $e_i$ (because if we subtract from $v$ some finite linear combination of $e_i$, we can still find some $i_n$ such that the result is not orthogonal to $e_{i_n}$).

You don't need $I$ to be countable.

On the other hand, if you have a Hilbert space of Hilbert dimension at least $\mathfrak c$, then the Hilbert dimension and Hamel dimension do coincide (but with different bases). They also coincide with the cardinality of the space, in this case.

Comment: Why statement in last paragraph true i.e. if you have a Hilbert space of Hilbert dimension at least c, then the Hilbert dimension and Hamel dimension do coincide

Comment: @Sushil: I see now that I have been a little rash. You can express every element of the space, uniquely, as an infinite linear combination of a countable set of the basis vectors. This implies that if the Hilbert dimension is $\kappa$ where $\kappa^\omega=\kappa\neq 0$ (which is true for $\kappa=\mathfrak c$, or any $\kappa=\lambda^\omega$), then the cardinality of the space is equal to $\kappa$, and therefore so is the Hamel dimension. On the other hand, the cardinality of the Hilbert space of Hilbert dimension $\aleph_\omega$ is $\aleph_\omega^\omega>\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: @Sushil: Well, that is what I *think* I had in mind, anyway, considering I wrote it half a year ago.

Comment: @Sushil: So the last statement is false: it is easy to see that the cardinality of an infinite dimensional vector space is the dimension times the cardinality of a field. So the Hilbert space of (Hilbert) dimension $\kappa$, where $\kappa>\mathfrak c$ has cofinality $\omega$ will have Hamel dimension $\kappa^\omega>\kappa$. Still, this answer is not very popular, so I'd rather not needlessly bump it just to fix this mistake.

Comment: Ok I got it. Just to confirm. Hamel basis dimension is same as that of cardinality of space in infinite dimensional vector space. Is it true? And why k^w>k for k>c?

Comment: @Sushil: Hamel dimension coincides with cardinality of the space if the dimension is not smaller than the cardinality of the underlying field (so $\mathfrak c$ in case of real/complex Hilbert spaces). To see this, just recall that an infinite set is equinumerous with the set of its finite subsets. I did not say that $\kappa^\omega>\kappa$ for $\kappa>\mathfrak c$, but there are such numbers $\kappa$, including (but possibly not limited to) those of cofinality $\omega$, due to König's lemma. And example of such a number is $\beth_\omega$.

Comment: Hamel dimension coincides with cardinality of the space if the dimension is not smaller than the cardinality of the underlying field. This must be true if field is infinite. Am I right? because vector space V will be equinumerous to Cartesian product of set of finite subsets of B and set of finite subsets of  F(B is basis and F field)

Comment: @Sushil: More or less, yes.

Comment: sorry don't what is ℵω. But I think if we assume GCH then κ^ω=κ

Comment: @Sushil: No, this is not true for arbitrary infinite $\kappa$.

Comment: why not. all k except ω will be of form 2^aleph. Am I right where alpeh will be a countable or uncountable cardinal and alpeh.ω=alpeh

Comment: @Sushil: No, this is not true. GCH implies that every *successor* cardinal is of this form, but there are other cardinals as well. This discussion is very much beyond the scope of this question. I suggest you read a text to acquaint yourself with basic cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: Oh I see. I need to study about limit ordinal and limit cardinal first. May you please give some reference.

Comment: @Sushil: Not really. Jech's set theory probably contains everything you need to know and more, but it might not be the right text for you.

Comment: I'll see but for time being I got your argument. instead of ℵω, I can take union of w, 2^w, 2^2^w and so on where w is cardinality of N. And this union will satisfy strict inequality because of Konig's Lemma